# Extjs Grid panel one column background Color change on another column value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have an Extjs Editor Grid panel in which i have to change the css of one column depending upon the value of another column value then how to do it i cannot use renderer function because it works on onload is there any other way i am attaching code in which i have gender column and id column so when gender column select male then background colour of ID should change to Pink colour else not so how to do it.

```
  {
            id: 'value',
            name: 'value',
            header: 'Gender',
            dataIndex: 'insured',
            width: 100,
            editor: new fm.ComboBox({

                typeAhead: true,
                displayField: 'gender',
                mode: 'local',
                transform: 'gender',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnFocus: true,
                forceSelection: true,
                stripeRows: true,
                lazyRender: true,
                listeners: {

                    }
                }
            })
        },
  {
        id: 'ID',
        name: 'ID',
        header: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'ID',
        width: 100,
        hidden: true,
        editor: new fm.TextField({
            allowBlank: true,
            maxLength: 500
        })
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, renderer gets called each team the record value changes. So you actually can use renderer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for simple rendering

**CSS:**

```
.custom-column
{
    background-color: #ccc; 
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'name',
    renderer: function (value, meta) {
        meta.css = 'custom-column';
        return value;
    }
}]
```

### Edit:

You can use [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) to apply custom CSS classes to rows during rendering.

> Override this function to apply custom CSS classes to rows during
>   rendering. This function should return the CSS class name (or empty
>   string '' for none) that will be added to the row's wrapping div. To
>   apply multiple class names, simply return them space-delimited within
>   the string (e.g. 'my-class another-class').

**Javascript:**

```
columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'ID',
    ...
    tdCls: 'ID' //add table css class
}],

viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index) {
        var gender = record.get('insured');

        if (gender === 0) {
        //male
            return 'gender-male';
        } else if (gender === 1) {
        //female
            return 'gender-female';
        } else {
        //unknown
            return 'gender-unknown';
        }
    }
}
```

Additional **CSS:**

```
.gender-male .ID {
    background-color: #088da5;
}
.gender-female .ID {
    background-color: #f799af;
}
.gender-unknown .ID {
    background-color: #BADA55;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering ...but my problem is that i am using extjs editor grid panel and i have already used renderer to change the background colour of some column ...but my problem is that when gender combobox will select male then only ID column background colour change to some other colour otherwise not so ....can you give me some sample code means i am using beforeshow function of id ..and inside that i want to change background colour thanks

Comment: Edited my answer ;) let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: hii applied but still i didnot get i am using Extjs 3.4 and i want this css to apply only after selecting gender as yes so that it should affect to other column of extjs editor grid panel instantly like listener change...and using this get row class i am not getting gender value i used alert ..

Comment: hee thanks for replying i have solved my problem...using renderer function ...thanks again

Comment: definetely , and your answer is also right i tried with that renderer function first one and it worked fine with no issues.... i hope we will be in touch